# myData.map is not a function , TypeError: myData.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, axios

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Aside = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

  // using Promises
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://dummyjson.com/products")
      .then((response) => setMyData(response.data))
  }, []);

//plz subscribe to thapa technical
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Axios Tutorial</h1>

      <div className="grid">
        {myData.map((post) => {
          const {  id, title } = post;
          return (
            <div key={id} className="card">
              <h2>{title}</h2>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Aside;
```

please give a solution for this error

Comment: You need to use `myData.products.map(...)`. If you look at the response, it gives a `"products"` array nested on the first level..

Answer (score 0):

Your very first debugging step should be to observe the actual data you're receiving from this URL:

```
https://dummyjson.com/products
```

When doing so, you'll find that it's *not an array*.  It's an object with the following structure:

```
{
  products: [
    /...lots of objects.../
  ],
  total: 100,
  skip: 0,
  limit: 30
}
```

It's an *object*, which has a *property* that is an array.  If that array is what you want, set your state to that array:

```
setMyData(response.data.products)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the response, it gives a `"products"` array nested on the first level..
So, you need to use `myData.products.map(...)`.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Aside = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

  // using Promises
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://dummyjson.com/products")
      .then((response) => setMyData(response.data))
  }, []);

//plz subscribe to thapa technical
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Axios Tutorial</h1>

      <div className="grid">
        {myData.products.map((post) => { /* << CHANGE HERE */
          const {  id, title } = post;
          return (
            <div key={id} className="card">
              <h2>{title}</h2>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Aside;
```